# Jquery formdata post with express js

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, express, multer

I want to submit a form data that contains file type input and normal input and receive it in the express post request. I am using multer npm package to save the file.

HTML

```
<form  id="abc" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
   <input type="text" id="firstname">
   <button class="formsubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.formsubmit', function(req, res){
    var form = $('#abc')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    data.append("name", $('#firstname').val());
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/sendformdata',
        data: data,
        contentType: false, 
        dataType: 'json',
        cache : false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(res) {
            console.log("Success"); 
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
}
```

Express

```
app.post('/sendformdata',(req,res) => {
   console.log("body: ", req.body);    // output: {}
   console.log("body: ", req.query);   // output: {}
   console.log("body: ", req.fields);  // output: undefined

   upload(req,res,function(err){
       if(err){
           console.log(err)
       }else{
           path = req.file.path   
       }
   })
}

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
}).single("inputfile");
```

I am not been able to receive the text type input in the express request though req.file is available.

Please note if someone has a better package or solution for uploading the file. I just don't want to use action in form tag to capture the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check when you create the newFormData if there's actually any data in there?. Also check the network tab to see what is your requests sending to the server.

Make sure you route and controller are setup properly, I leave and example on how you could do that.

```
   // SET STORAGE
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
      }
    })
     
    const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Set up the route and controller correctly. I will recomend you to have the route in one file and the controller in another. But up to you.

```
  app.post('/uploadfile', upload.single('fileNameInForm'), (req, res, next) => {
  const { file, body } = req;
  
})
```